# Windows 7 fails to see Super Disk drive

Tags: windows-7, floppy, removable-media, disk-drive

Windows 7 x64 fails to see my internal IDE Super Disk drive, but Lubuntu 18.04 x64 does see it. I know it's not the IDE interface or cable that's the problem because it will detect a slave IDE HDD perfectly fine (the ls120 doesn't like being a slave). The IDE controller is configured to be JBOD.

My computer doesn't have a floppy connector, so I use a Super Disk drive to read and write floppies. I can't simply use a USB floppy drive, as they don't write to 720Ks, or write in the Atari format.

How can I make Windows see the drive?

IDE controller - HighPoint HPT3xx ATA RAID controller (PCI)

Super Disk drive - Panasonic LKM-F934-1 Ls120

MoBo - (Whatever comes with a Dell Optiplex 780)

Comment: If you attach another IDE device to the controller, say a hard drive, does it see that?  Did you configure the RAID for JBOD or similar?

Comment: @cybernard updated question with asked details

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check the setting of IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers in "Device Manager".

1. Enable "ATA Channel 1".

[image]

2.Set the "Device Type" of "ATA Channel 1" in its properties, default setting is "None", we change it to " Detect automatically "(if you can change the "Device Type").

[image]

3. Right-click "ATA Channel 1", select "Scan for hardware changes" .
4. View if we can see super disk drive.

If the above is not useful, we can try to troubleshoot the issue by the following steps.

1.Disconnect the network, then reconnect the network, right-click "ATA Channel 1", select "Scan for hardware changes", and view if Microsoft can detect the corresponding drive of super disk automatically ,we can see it in the lower right corner icon of the computer. If Microsoft can detect its drive, it can reinstall its drive automatically.

2.View if we can see super disk drive.

3.If Microsoft can not find its drive, we can reinstall the drive of  Dell Optiplex 780.

4.View if we can see super disk drive.

5.If we can still not see super disk drive after reinstalling the drive of  Dell Optiplex 780.

6.We can find the latest drive of Panasonic LKM-F934-1 Ls120 and reinstall it.

7.View if we can see super disk drive.

Comment: My 0-3 ATA channels were my 0-3 SATA channels, and ATA 5 was my eSATA port. I didn't see PATA channels,even with a PATA HDD connected. And I do not understand what you mean by "reinstall the drive of Dell Optiplex 780".

Comment: I means reinstall the motherboard drive of your computer.